# authentication with bcrypt on flask without database

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

i have created password authentication with bcrypt on flask not with database. so the story is that I want to login the password using a hashed password. but can't even log me in. is there something wrong???

@auth.verify_password
def authenticate(username, password):

```
user = 'alfara'
passwd = 'alfara'

if username and password:
    pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(passwd).decode('utf-8')
    if username == user and password == pw_hash:
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(pw_hash, passwd)
    else:
        return False
return False
```

Comment: The idea of password hashing is that you do not store the clear text password. Your code fail in this. You could just compare `passwd` and `password` directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The idea of password hashing is that you do not store the clear text password. Your code fail in this. You could just compare passwd and password directly.

- @Klaus D.

If you want, you can do

```py
passwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash("alfara")
```

Then do it like this

```py
if username and password:
    verify = bcrypt.check_password_hash(passwd, password)
    if verify and username == user:
        return "Username and Password Matched"
```